# New to Laravel, trying to integrate Square Payment Form

Tags: laravel, square-connect

I've been following the instructions on Square's [website](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/setup).

I've got all the code I need plugged into my application as shown on square, but the asset('js/square.js') call didn't find the file for some reason. So, I just added the script to the end of the resources/js/app.js file, doesn't seem to have any errors but the form doesn't look right.[image: Square's form].

Comment: Can you actually click where it says "Card Number" and type? It looks like it might be just a styling (CSS) issue, but not 100% sure based on the image.

Comment: not at all. here's the HTML  for the form....

Comment: Do you see any console errors in your browser after the page loads, then?

Comment: When i tried pulling in the script as suggested on Square's site. (ex: <script src="{{ asset('js/square.js')}}" defer></script>) I did get an error stating that the file couldn't be found.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. And do you have that file? You need to create a JS file with the payment form initialization and to handle the callbacks.

Comment: No problem. Decided to use Stripe API instead. I'd still like to figure it out it time, project is just time sensitive.

Comment: No worries. To better assist you (whenever you have time to figure it out), I'd suggest joining us over on Slack as we'll be able to respond a lot quicker and help you troubleshoot: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE

Answer (score 0):

```html
                   <form id="nonce-form" novalidate action="PATH/TO/PAYMENT/PROCESSING/PAGE" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <fieldset>
                            <span class="label">Card Number</span>
                            <div id="sq-card-number"></div>

                            <div class="third">
                                <span class="label">Expiration</span>
                                <div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="third">
                                <span class="label">CVV</span>
                                <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="third">
                                <span class="label">Postal</span>
                                <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">Pay $1.00</button>

                        <div id="error"></div>

                        <!--
                          After a nonce is generated it will be assigned to this hidden input field.
                        -->
                        <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
                    </form>
```